# Debian 11 USB access issue for "0"-starting usernames

Tags: usb, debian, mount

I have a problem that in my system usernames have to start with "0" which makes impossible for users to access encrypted USBs. There is an error:

> Couldn't mount "Encrypted volume (n GB)" 
>  Not authorized to perform operation

after I enter correct password into regular prompt.
I have already tried:

1. Temporarly deleting and changing ACLs to /media where mount folders appear for users not starting with "0"
2. Setting 666 permissions for /media
3. mounting directory as root (I need dislocker to perform this action, but policy prohibits using it)

Is there any way that I can bypass authorization error locally on a computer for 0-starting usernames?

Comment: does this occur in, for example, latest Fedora LiveUSB?

Comment: @user1686 No, and I fail to understand how that would be helpful for me. This is probably an issue related to what Bib said below an hour ago.

Comment: it tells you whether the issue has been fixed in later versions of some software (e.g. systemd or policykit) that may be available in Debian 12

Answer (score 0):

From the useradd man page:

> Usernames must start with a lower case letter or an underscore,
> followed by lower case letters, digits, underscores, or dashes. They
> can end with a dollar sign. In regular expression terms:
> [a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*[$]?

I assume some part of the system is getting mixed up when presented a var with a leading zero and then expecting it to be an octal number or it is expecting a numerical id rather than an ascii name.

Moral of this story - always adhere to the required specifications of a system.

Comment: Is there a way to bpass problem you mentioned? Unfortunatley "0"-starting usernames are - let's say -  company policy and I cannot change that.

Comment: Your company has to change policy. No "ifs", no "buts". Whoever decided that, did so without knowledge of how a system works.